# Сtrl+Break не работает

Tags: c++, pascal, клавиатура

ctrl+break не работает в dosbox

программирую в turbo c++ в dosbox, не могу завершить срочно программу во время выполнения, dosbox не принимает ctrl+break. в keymapper dosbox не знаю как сделать чтобы принимал. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: А ctrl-c? Если Вы используете TurboVision или что-то подобное, то они намеренно отключают реакцию на ctrl-break.

Comment: @Ddd ЕМНИП, и Ctrc-C отключен